# What is the best way to load and read very large multiple csv files into Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, memory-management

I'm currently working with 234 csv files, each of them has 1 million of rows. I've tried to use vaex and dask to read and concatenate them (it did work very well) but it takes too long and raise too many errors when I try to join with other dataframes. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Put them in a database and don't try to work with them in-memory.

Comment: The second part of your question is not specific. Please outline what kind of errors are raised, what kind of joins you are using, etc. Generally, dask for instance is a good tool for applications where you do rowwise operations, but not great if calculations are performed across columns. But without specific goals of your code, it is hard to make suggestions

Comment: If the data is static, it will be well worth your time to convert each of them to arrow, hdf5 or parquet via vaex, and work with them in an out-of-core manner. The performance is terrific. 

As for joining with other dataframes, they also need to be vaex. 

In principle you could do the same with dask.dataframe, just convert everything to parquet. But in my experience vaex is faster. 

Of course if you convert them to parquet you can use both vaex and dask.dataframe

Comment: Joco, I converted all the csv files to parquet and read them with vaex. The performance is really terrific, but I still can't do a join :/ 
Everytime I try to do a join, I get a Memory Error: bad allocation

Comment: Do  you by any chance have missing/None/NaN values on one of the keys you are doing the join? If so, that is a known bug (unfortunately).

Otherwise could you please open an issue at  https://github.com/vaexio/vaex/issues